# jQuery .val() not working when setting a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have an input like so:

```
<input type="text" id="textvalue" />
```

the following code will change its value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textvalue').val("hello");
});
```

however the following will not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var = "hello";
    $('#textvalue').val(var);
});
```

Why does the second one not work? I need to be able to change the value of the textbox to the value of a variable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `var` statement needs to look something like this

```
var something = "hello"

$('#textvalue').val(something );
```

Right now your not actually assigning a value to a variable, and then you are trying to use the `var` keyword.

**[Variable Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)**

Comment: Yes, var is a reserved word not a "variable"

Answer (score 7):

[`var` is a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), which means it can't be used as a variable name. If you try:

```
var variable = "hello";

$('#textvalue').val(variable);
```

it would work.

Just for interest: `var` is used to *declare* variables, as above.

Comment: I see you beat me to it. Promoting yours since it got up there first.

Answer (score 0):

var is a reserved word in JavaScript because you use it to declare a variable and you are therefore declaring an empty variable.

Use this:

```
$anything = "hello";
$('#textvalue').val($anything);
```

Obviously you can replace anything with whatever you want, just don't use var.

Naming conventions are pretty important, you should have a meaningful name for each variable, ideally.

Comment: This is an JavaScript anti pattern. Without var keyword you are creating global variable and thus polluting global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myHello = "hello";
    $('#textvalue').val(myHello);
});
```

You have to assign your text to a variable with name. var itself is a keyword.