# .val() is not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we also pass string values to some variable and call through below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = "1, 2, 3";
    $('#textvalue').val(i);
});
```

does it work?

Its not working don't know how :(

There is one more post related to this

Link: [jQuery .val() not working when setting a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327331/jquery-val-not-working-when-setting-a-variable)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `somearray` is not an array.

Comment: As ThiefMaster says, you have a string, not an array. If it was an array, what were you expecting the result to be?

Comment: you code works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/r9c2d/

Comment: First, you don't have an array in the code presented. So I would expect the value of your `#textvalue` element to be the string `[1, 2, 3]`. Second, what behavior would expect by passing an array instead of a string?

Answer (score 1):

If `#textvalue` is a `<select multiple>` element you can set its value to an array which will select all options with values in the array:

```
var somearray = [1, 2, 3];
$('#textvalue').val(somearray);
```

However, for any other element an array makes no sense and thus it will be converted to a string or simply fail.

Anyway, the *string* you have in `somearray` can be assigned without problems to any input element (except `type="file"` of course).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/XKgFy/2/

Set the value attr with your string, then split it back to an array:

```
var somearray = "1, 2, 3";
$('#textvalue').attr('value',somearray).on('click', function(){
    var arr = $(this).attr('value').split(', ');
    $('<p>').html("Your array has " + arr.length + " elements").appendTo($('body'));
});
```